# Purity, Power, and Promise

Tags: riddle

Maybe another easy one, maybe not. (Can include title)

*I am the horror that lurks behind the glass.*
    *I am often one shape, but I can wear many.*
    *I am the stability between two.*

*What am I?*

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Probably not, but made me think of

> A ring

I am the horror that lurks behind the glass.

> Engagement rings! YIKES!

Edit: Oh right...

> The movie "The Ring" about a demon thingy that comes out of the TV screen (which used to be made of convex glass) to attack people that watch a cursed video tape (an ancient recording device)

I am often one shape, but I can wear many.

> Yep; there are some pretty kooky designs

I am the stability between two.

> Wedding rings...

Purity, Power, and Promise

> Promise rings, Purity rings, Rings of power

Comment: This is what I am going for, however not for the glass line, I'll accept it eventually but think less like the other lines for that one.

Comment: Thought about it and made the edit but I think mine fits better lol

Comment: Haha yeah that's what I was going for originally but totally get both fitting, nice job

Answer (score 1):

Maybe a bit too much of an imaginative solution but:

> An eye?

```
I am the horror that lurks behind the glass.
```

> Behind each lens on a pair of glasses is an eye

```
I am often one shape, but I can wear many.
```

> Usually spherical, but there a lot of species with different shaped eyes

```
I am the stability between two.
```

> Bit weak, but it transfers what you see (the first) to the brain (the second) and is in between.

Comment: Nope not it, but interesting thought

Answer (score 1):

How about:

> a reflection?

```
I am the horror that lurks behind the glass.
```

> a piece of glass can like a mirror show some reflection behind it

```
I am often one shape, but I can wear many.
```

> Your own reflection is always the same but of course you can see other objects in the reflection also

```
I am the stability between two.
```

> Maybe to indicate that you and your reflection are identical

Comment: Nice idea! I'm struggling with the last line too...

Comment: Oh that's a super interesting thought! But nope

Answer (score 0):

Is it

> Mannequin

I am the horror that lurks behind the glass.

> Mannequins stand behind the display glass of the showrooms

I am often one shape, but I can wear many.

> One mannequin can wear different size clothes

I am the stability between two.

> Not sure about this one.

Comment: Nope no it, goood connections for those first two though... think about the title too it may help